# Naming primary keys "id" vs "something_id" in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, naming-conventions, primary-key

I'm wondering what the best practice is for naming primary/unique keys in a database with many tables. Should you always just call each table's primary key `id` or is ok to not have an `id` field in each table and just name each of them `something1_id`, `something2_id`, etc?

Comment: `something_id` is redundant when you can use `table.id` everywhere... unless you're putting in a foreign key.

Comment: I have always wondered what people think of the pros and cons of the approaches

Comment: the foreign key issue is the reason why "ID" can be confusing - because you then have to create a relationship with "somethingID" in a different table; you're creating relationships on fields with different names.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Whatever you do, pick one or the other and stick to that standard.**  There are pros and cons for each.

I prefer `SomethingID` but other people prefer just `ID`.  In the system I work with there are well over a thousand tables and having the PK and the FK have the exact same names makes things easier.

Comment: hi KM, thanks. So just as long as there is no clearly superior way, I think i'll stick with `somethingID`.

Comment: @tim peterson, it all depends on how you use SQL and what works for you.  The key point of the query is to get the info back fast, and the column name will not affect that, index usage will.

Comment: The absolute worst thing is DBs that use more than one naming convention. I've worked on a system that used 4 different naming conventions for surrogate PKs.

Answer (score 14):

It's personal preference.  At the end of the day it makes absolutely no difference.  I personally prefer using just `Id` as I find referring to the field (let's say `Customer` table and `Id` field) `Customer.CustomerId` to be cumbersome, where `Customer.Id` seems to make more sense.

Comment: In addition, While creating reference Tablename_id is required so while firing query we can use `parent p, child c where p.id = c.parent_id`

Comment: The only thing it won't let you do is using the `USING` keyword: `SELECT ... FROM table_a JOIN table_b USING (something_id)`

Answer (score 6):

It *is* a matter of preference; however, there is an advantage to using (something)ID in that column names become less ambiguous when you are doing joins between tables.

Comment: yes, thanks i agree, this question came about as I've written more and more JOINs...

Comment: There's an advantage for both when doing joins. I prefer `id` for the column name as I will be listing the table names before columns in *all* joins anyway, so `tablename_id` or something similar is just extra, unneeded specificity.

Comment: @bfrohs: Yes, I agree including the table name in the ID column name involves a little more typing.

Answer (score 1):

`id` is just a convenient convention - you can call the field anything as long as you declare it as a key field.

Prefixing the id with a relevant context can be helpful when it comes to reading and writing your code, and especially improves readability when you are joining data from multiple tables and foreign keys.

Comment: (*Just a thought because your answer caught my eye and I was thinking about programming to an interface.*) True, and I agree, but the `id` approach translates table records to objects better, especially if you have an abstract super-class with an `id` property. If you do what you suggest (which I happen to do, too), then you must also manage the various `blahId` fields and properties when mapping table records to objects. That would be true for foreign keys that get translated to object properties anyway, but at least the abstract super-class could just have a simple property named `id`.

Comment: It can have an `id` property anyway, but your code would be more consistent horizontally across abstract super-classes if we used the `id`, especially when assigning the value of the `id` field to the `id` property. The clarity of the database might suffer some, but that can be mitigated by giving foreign keys `blahId` names. Those names will seep into the objects, but you'll be able to know what's what.

Answer (score -4):

I'd suggest you use an abbreviation for long names and use (something)Id (like `user_id`) for regular tables. So for the table `customer_company_relation_metadata` use `ccm_id`. But its fine to use `id` as well

Comment: Please don't use abbreviations in this context, it only obfuscate your code and is less readable for new(er) members to your team/code (and even yourself after a break). Good reading material: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/24083

Comment: @Styxxy I have found them to be the most useful way between having long column names (that are annoying in longer queries) and having to use `user.id` all the time. But its of course a matter of taste.

Comment: Very long names can be abbreviated, maybe. I wouldn't use it for user though (what are those 2 letters if you pay a lot in readability?). It is indeed partially your preference, but abbreviate to abbreviate is just plain wrong (I wouldn't want to maintain code like that).
PS: If you have a decent editor, even long names shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Styxxy Yeah, user is a bad example thats right. I'll edit it for a better one. And that doesn't apply to all code, only to SQL. We are totally together that its bad for other stuff.