# Problems with foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

Since I'm new to SQL Server, I think I need a little help here... Since I've rewritten the code below many times there might be other errors as well, sorry about that. Removed the 'GO' for now.

Problem:

I don't know how to create a foreign key from "model" in the table `Cars` to the table `Model`.

My broken code:

```
create table [Cars]
(
   [id] [int] not null primary key identity,
   [name] [nvarchar](50) not null,
   [weight] [int] not null,
   [length] [int] not null,
   [model] [nvarchar](50) not null,
   [color] [nvarchar](50) not null
);

create table [Colors]
(
   [id] [int] not null primary key identity,
   [name] [nvarchar](50) not null
);

create table [Model] 
(
    [id] [int] primary key not null identity,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) not null
);

insert into Cars(name, weight, length, model, color)
values('Ferrari', '1500', '4000', '360', 'Red');

insert into Colors values('Red');
insert into Colors values('Blue');
insert into Colors values('Yellow');

insert into Model values('Volvo');
insert into Model values('Fiat');
insert into Model values('Saab');

alter table Model
add foreign key (id)
references Cars(id)

alter table Colors
add foreign key (id)
references Cars(id)
```

Comment: This model is flawed and you should take a step back and rethink it. Using a foreign key relationship on the Color table to enforce that a color id exists as a car id doesn't make any sense at all. I'd suggest you read up on modeling a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code managed to solve the problem I think, several of you people here did contribute, thank you.

```
alter table Cars
add constraint fk_colors foreign key (colorid)
references colors([id])
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise against naming all your primary keys the same (`ID`) as this runs in to problems when creating foreign keys.

Your table `Cars` has `model` as `nvarchar`, which is unnecessary if you are using surrogate keys. Change the data type to `int`, the name to `model_id` and add a constraint to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE Cars
ADD CONSTRAINT FK$Model$id FOREIGN KEY (model_id)
REFERENCES Model(id)
```

As others have mentioned, your use of a foreign key in the `Colors` table is also incorrect.

Comment: I advise against @Tony's advice (in regards to ID as Primary Key name), as it means you are constantly guessing what the Primary Key of every table is. In practice this is likely to be a policy set by your Senior DBA, and you violate his policies at your peril. Both naming schemes are very viable, many developers get religious in their affirmation of one over the other, and the only true sin is inconsistency. Choose either one and use it everywhere, until the end of that lifetime/project.

Comment: @Pieter - my advice is to NOT have every PK as [ID], I think you may have misread my answer.

Comment: And mine is to HAVE every PK as [ID]. I did not misunderstand at all. Constantly typing TableName.TableNameID I see as simply a recipe for Carpal Tunnel.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - Ultimately it's personal preference, there are [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863872/id-or-tablenameid-as-primary-key-entity-identifier) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436953/naming-primary-keys-id-vs-something-id-in-sql) on SO discussing the merits of both. However, if your main reason for using [id] is simply to reduce the amount of typing you need to get some better SQL programming tools, such as Red Gate's _SQL Prompt_ (BTW I have no affiliation with Reg Gate)

Answer (score -1):

```
--Add column in Model as Car_ID
--then use

ALTER TABLE Model
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CarsID FOREIGN KEY(Car_ID) REFERENCES Cars(ID)
```

Comment: Why would you want to store the id of a car in the model table?

Comment: @jpw because 1 Car Can Have Multiple Models and without adding how can we maintain relation ships between two tables and i think in above question model and colors are not required in Cars tables it should be removed